# Whats a fast way to check that reference is a specific generic type?

Tags: c#, reflection

If I have a method with a parameter that's an interface, whats the fasts way to see if the interface's reference is of a specific generic type?

More specifically, if I have:

```
interface IVehicle{}

class Car<T> : IVehicle {}

CheckType(IVehicle param)
{
    // How do I check that param is Car<int>?
}
```

I'm also going to have to cast after the check. So if there is a way to kill 2 birds with one stone on this one let me know.

Comment: Did you mean for Car<T> to implement IVehicle?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To check if param is a `Car<int>` you can use "is" and "as" as normal:

```
CheckType(IVehicle param)
{
    Car<int> car = param as Car<int>;
    if (car != null)
    {
         ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Jon--Your C# book has been very helpful--thank you for it and the great interview on DNR. Given my history with your advice, I'm prone to just blindly believe you! Having said that, why isn't Nick's response (directly using is) the better way to do this?

Comment: @rp: 'as' keyword attempts to cast, and if it can't give you a null value. The 'is' check will require you to do the work twice, as the cast after the is check is just as expensive as the 'is'. As does it all and only does it once.

Comment: @rp: Binary Worrier is exactly right. But don't take any advice blindly, whether from me or anyone else :) (Glad you liked the book though.)

Answer (score 3):

Or, you can just do:

```
if(param is Car<int>)
{
    // Hey, I'm a Car<int>!
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not make this generic?

```
interface IVehicle{}

class Car<T> : IVehicle {

    public static bool CheckType(IVehicle param)
    {
        return param is Car<T>;
    }
}
```

...

```
Car<string> c1 = new Car<string>();
Car<int> c2 = new Car<int>();
Console.WriteLine(Car<int>.CheckType(c1));
Console.WriteLine(Car<int>.CheckType(c2));
```

Answer (score 1):

The code differs quite dramatically depending on whether you want to know, if the reference is based on a generic type prototype, or a specialized one.

The specialized one is easy, you can just use `is`:

```
CheckType(IVehicle param)
{
   var isofYourType = param is Car<int>;
   ...
}
```

or a safe cast, as shown before:

```
CheckType(IVehicle param)
{
   var value = param as Car<int>;
   if(value != null)    
       ...
}
```

In case you wanted to know whether yur var is just some specialization of `Car<T>`, things get really **ugly**.
And the last you should thing to worry about is speed in this case, because that's gonna be even uglier than the code *g*:

```
class Car<T>
{ }

interface IVehicle { }

class YourCar : Car<int>, IVehicle
{ }

static bool IsOfType(IVehicle param)
{
    Type typeRef = param.GetType();
    while (typeRef != null)
    {
        if (typeRef.IsGenericType &&
            typeRef.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Car<>))
        {
            return true;
        }
        typeRef = typeRef.BaseType;
    }
    return false;
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    IVehicle test = new YourCar();
    bool x = IsOfType(test);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I often find that if my code requires me to write checks for specific types, I'm probably doing something wrong.  You didn't give us enough context for us to give advice on this, though.

Does this meet your needs?

```
Car<int> carOfInt = param as Car<int>;
if (carOfInt != null)
{
    // .. yes, it's a Car<int>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the "as" operator to do it all in one shot.  "as" will return either an object of the type you want, or null if what you're checking against doesn't match.  This will only work for reference types, though.

```
interface IVehicle { }
class Car<T> : IVehicle 
{
    static Car<int> CheckType(IVehicle v)
    {
        return v as Car<int>;
    }
}
```

The "is" operator will let you test to see if `v` is an instance of `Car<int>`.